# Cannot Extend Django 1.2.1 Admin Template

Tags: django, django-admin

I am attempting to override/extend the header for the Django admin in version 1.2.1. However when I try to extend the admin template and simply change what I need  documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template), I run into a recursion problem.

I have an index.html file in my project's templates/admin/ directory that starts with

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
```

But it seems that this is referencing the local index file (a.k.a. itself) rather than the default Django copy. I want to extend the default Django template and simply change a few blocks. When I try this file, I get a recursion depth error.

How can I extend parts of the admin? Thanks.

SOLUTION: Rather than extending, I copied the files into my_templates_directory/admin/ and just edited them as I wished. This solution was acceptable, though not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Rather than extending, I copied the files into my_templates_directory/admin/ and just edited them as I wished. This solution was acceptable, though not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The `contrib/admin/templates/admin` path needs to go before the directory with your custom admin templates in your list of paths in  `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py`

Comment: I put "C:/Python26/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin" before my project template directory in TEMPLATE_DIRS, but I still cannot get the template overrriding working. I am still using the same extends line from my original post. Does that need changed as well?

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink to `contrib/admin/templates/admin/` in your templates directory and use it in your `{% extends %}` statement.

```
cd /path/to/project/templates/
ln -s /path/to/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/ django_admin
```

Now in your `admin/index.html` use `{% extends "django_admin/index.html" %}`

**EDIT:** Just realized that you're on windows... Not sure how to achieve the same results. Hopefully this still helps the folks on linux.