# Difficulty overriding Django Admin template

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.2.4 on Ubuntu 10.10. I'm trying to override the index.html template for the admin module. I've been following these [instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). I also looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993233/cannot-extend-django-1-2-1-admin-template), but I'm still having difficulty.

The instructions say to create an `admin` directory in the templates directory:

```
templates/
    admin/
         index.html
```

I want to override a single block in the `index.html`. (Really, all I want to do is append some text to the end. Is there an easier way than copy/pasting the entire block and changing it?) (**Update**: Looks like `{{block.super}}` may help.)

To signal that I'm overriding, I put this at the top of my `index.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
```

Of course, that results in a stack overflow (from the terminal):

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
```

What is the correct way to do this? I tried a symlink per an answer on the linked question, but that resulted in the following:

```
me@mycomp:~/foo$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/ django_admin
[sudo] password for me: 
ln: creating symbolic link `django_admin': Protocol error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

The recursion error is because you're extending the `admin/index.html` with itself.

You can either:

- copy the entire `admin/index.html` template in your `templates/admin/` directory, and it will replace the default template with yours
- override the `index.html` per app or model, as explained [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

I know this is late after the question, but you know, google traveling...

Answer (score 7):

Amend settings.py with an extra template folder, for example:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/home/mysite/webapps/django/myproject/templates",
    "/home/mysite/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/",  # extra folder
)
```

Then in myproject/templates/admin add your own index.html like:

```
{% extends "contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html" %}

{% block branding %}
    <h1 id="site-name">Administration for TheLittleButtonCo</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Variations are possible, obviously. This works on Django 1.3.1 final

Comment: how do you specify a path to the jdango install without hardcoding it ?

Comment: @maazza: `import django; os.path.dirname(django.__file__)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found the answer, but you need to change

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
```

to

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
```

as that is what the original index.html page overwrites. Because the Django system searches your templates folder before using the default admin one, so in this case it finds the admin/index.html in your templates, then it's trying to extend itself with the extend (hence the recursion error).

For reference you can customise the `base_site.html` in you templates too, it extends `base.html`. The best thing to do is copy the original from:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/
```

and paste it into your templates folder as a starting point

Answer (score 1):

I use an extra package, called [django-smart-extends](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-extends)