# How to add top save button on django admin change list?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to have a save button on top of django admin change list page. It seems that django don't have this functionality built-in. The save_on_top option only controls behavior on change form page. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: What is there to save when you're on a change list page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need a way to extend the template found at `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html`. If you don't already know how to do that, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586068/237244) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267927/237244).

Next, you need to create your own `change_list.html` template and put code similar to the following in it. For the sake of simplicity, I've included inline CSS. However, this is bad practice, so you should not do it. Assuming you move the CSS to an external file, you won't need to load `admin_static`. Lastly, the `extends` line that you use might not be exactly the same as what I've shown here.

```
{% extends "contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static %}

{% block result_list %}
    {% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; background: white url({% static "admin/img/nav-bg.gif" %}) 0 180% repeat-x; overflow: hidden;">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="_save" class="default" value="{% trans 'Save' %}"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

The `{% if %}` tag and the `<input>` tag inside of it is from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/pagination.html`.

The CSS is based on the CSS for `#changelist .paginator` and is found in `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/changelists.css`.

Comment: This answer works great, but instead of inline CSS or external an CSS file, an alternative would be be to give the the 'div' tag a class of pagination, <div class="pagination"> for nearly the same result.

Answer (score 11):

In Django 3 (and maybe earlier, not sure) in your custom admin form add `save_on_top = True`

```py
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_on_top = True
```

Comment: From the question "The save_on_top option only controls behavior on change form page."

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind having pagination links at the top of the page as well, you can do it with a few lines of template code, worksforme in Django 2.0.

Create `my_app/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/change_list.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load admin_list %}

{% block result_list %}
    {% pagination cl %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

This will render the pagination *and* the save button:

[image]

Could benefit from a line or two of CSS, though...